# Http request error

Tags: http

Is there any limitations on sending http requests. I send them in cycle from my programm, and all goes alright at first, but then, an error comes, saying that request failed because target machine refused connection. Can the error be on my side, or it is targets fault?

Comment: I forgot to mention I send requests to my own server and there is no protection for dos attack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these requests staying open? I believe in the HTTP spec there is a limit to the number of open connections as I remember it is quite low.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the target machine detects that you're sending a lot of requests in a short amount of time, and therefore decides to deny you access (as it looks like a DOS attack). Try having a small pause (say, 100ms) between each request.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making too many requests in a short interval, many hosts will block your IP address. This is usually by design, and a protection against automated page scraping. Slowing down your request rate might help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually web servers will be configured so that they only allow a certain number of requests to be made from a particular client per second / minute / hour. So if you're getting an HTTP error after making a few requests it's the server blocking you're IP. You'll need to act nice and have a timeout between the requests, how long exactly depends on the server and you'll need to figure it out by trial and error.